# Flatten array in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, kotlin, flatten

I have a two dimensional array of Nodes that I want to flatten into a single array of all nodes using the flatten function of Kotlin arrays.

```
    val nodes = kotlin.Array(width, { width ->
    kotlin.Array(height, { height -> Node(width, height) })
})
```

I then try to call the flatten function on the 2D array

```
nodes.flatten()
```

but I get an error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Array<Node>> but Array<Array<out ???>> was expected`. Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: Specify your error more precisely, use the original error message.

Comment: added the actual error message

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays in Kotlin are [invariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays) so an `Array<Array<Node>>` is not an `Array<Array<out T>>` (which is the receiver type for `flatten`).

It looks like this will be fixed in Kotlin 1.1: [Relax generic variance in Array.flatten · JetBrains/kotlin@49ea0f5](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/49ea0f5984a90e5f2091be4a662994f0be567d8b).

Until Kotlin 1.1 is released you can maintain your your own version of `flatten`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns a single list of all elements from all arrays in the given array.
>  */
> fun <T> Array<out Array<out T>>.flatten(): List<T> {
>     val result = ArrayList<T>(sumBy { it.size })
>     for (element in this) {
>         result.addAll(element)
>     }
>     return result
> }
> ```

Comment: For the record, the same flatten method applies to lists.

Answer (score 23):

Use a more universal `flatMap`:

```
nodes.flatMap {it.asIterable()}
```